# Firefox extension debugging - how can I enable showing info about syntax error in error console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Currently I use manual workaround like binary search: "delete half of potentially invalid code, check whatever extension loads, repeat for other half, repeat for potentially invalid code".

setting dom.report_all_js_exceptions to true described in [How to detect syntax errors when debugging Firefox extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430688/how-to-detect-syntax-errors-when-debugging-firefox-extensions) failed to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [Bug 986689](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=986689) in v30 and newer.

For now I'm using older version of Firefox. v29 seems to be the latest that still shows the errors.

Another possible solution is to use

```
try
{
  //code here
}
catch(ex)
{
  //error captured
  dump(ex)
}
```

and output in console ex in catch (although it won't help with syntax errors)

Comment: I use v28 (as AFAIK v29 decided to again ruin interface and I currently have no time to fix it).

Comment: Did you set all the preferences as per this list?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Recommended_development_preferences